# Get files which are created in last 5 minutes in hadoop using shell script

Tags: shell, unix, hadoop, hdfs

I have files in HDFS as:

```
drwxrwx---   - root supergroup          0 2016-08-19 06:21 /tmp/logs/root/logs/application_1464962104018_1639064
drwxrwx---   - root supergroup          0 2016-08-19 06:21 /tmp/logs/root/logs/application_1464962104018_1639065
```

Now `/tmp/logs/root/logs/` directory will continuously get the new files in it.
I want to get the files which are created in last five minutes, taking current time into account. Then I need to copy these files into my local machine.

Answer (score 8):

How about this:

```
hdfs dfs -ls /tmp | tr -s " " | cut -d' ' -f6-8 | grep "^[0-9]" | awk 'BEGIN{ MIN=5; LAST=60*MIN; "date +%s" | getline NOW } { cmd="date -d'\''"$1" "$2"'\'' +%s"; cmd | getline WHEN; DIFF=NOW-WHEN; if(DIFF < LAST){ print $3 }}'
```

Explanation:

List all the files:

> hdfs dfs -ls /tmp

Replace extra spaces:

> tr -s " "

Get the required columns:

> cut -d' ' -f6-8

Remove non-required rows:

> grep "^[0-9]"

Processing using awk:

> awk

Initialize the DIFF duration and current time:

> MIN=5; LAST=60*MIN; "date +%s" | getline NOW

Create a command to get the epoch value for timestamp of the file on HDFS:

> cmd="date -d'\''"$1" "$2"'\'' +%s";

Execute the command to get epoch value for HDFS file:

> cmd | getline WHEN;

Get the time difference:

> DIFF=NOW-WHEN;

Print the output depending upon the difference:

> if(DIFF < LAST){ print $3 }

You just need to change the variable value for `MIN` depending upon your requirement (here its 5 minutes).
HTH

Comment: I am trying 

HADOOP_DIRECTORY_ARRAY=($(hadoop fs -ls /tmp/log/root/log | awk '{ if ((($6 == "$get_from_date" && $7 <= "$get_from_time") && ($6 == "$get_to_date" && $7 >= "$get_to_time"))) print $8 } '))
HADOOP_DIRECTORY_ARRAY=($(hadoop fs -ls /tmp/log/root/log | awk '{"$awk_string"}' ))

But in place of $6,$7 and $8 nothing is coming, date and time values are getting reflected.

Comment: It seems lil complicated, I need the easy one. Something easy to understand.
Thanks for the reply.

Comment: HDFS does not support this out of the box, just like what Linux provides e.g. `find /tmp -cmin -5`. Above solution is not complex. Just that it has multiple pipes which do one thing at a time. Instead of a single command, you can try using individual commands separately in your shell script.

Comment: When I execute the same in a shell script with hard coded values it works for me. Might be some issue with awk variable replacement ?


`#!/bin/bash
HADOOP_DIRECTORY_ARRAY=($(hadoop fs -ls /tmp/log/root/log | awk     '{ if ( ($6 < "'"2016-08-21"'" || ($6 == "'"2016-08-21"'" && $7 <= "'"20:00"'"))) print $8 } '))

echo "SIZE : " ${#HADOOP_DIRECTORY_ARRAY[@]}`

Comment: @MohitRane , if you have resolved your issue, please post your answer or if above solution works for you or helps in any way, the at least upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it using below command : it will give me files that are created between a five minute window :

```
hadoop fs -ls /tmp/logs/root/logs | awk '{ if ((($6 == "'"2016-08-18"'" && $7 <= "'"21:00"'") && ($6 == "'"2016-08-18"'" && $7 >= "'"20:55"'"))) print $8 } '
```

It can be modified accordingly with current time stamp.

Comment: The hard-coded values for the date have to be changed, every time you execute this command.