# move files which are older than X days to target directory in HDFS

Tags: shell, hadoop

I have a source folder, it consists of nested sub-directories. I want to move all the .txt files which are older than 2 days, present in 
source & nested sub-directories to target directory in Hadoop.

Something like this might move files from source to target.

```
hadoop fs -mv /user/source/*.txt /user/target
```

How do I move the .txt files which are older than 2 days?

Comment: Very similar you deletion operation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44235019/delete-files-older-than-10days-on-hdfs

Answer (score -1):

You can use find commands beautiful parameter that allows us to use some commands with it which is -exec

```
find /user/source/*.txt -type f -mtime 2 -exec mv '{}' /user/target \;
```

But sometimes this gives some problem with files so in case of this you can try this script as well.You need to create the directory tree from subdir1/subdir2/ - You could do, for example:

```
find /user/source/*.txt -type f -mtime +2 -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file;do
        dir="${file%/*}"
        mkdir -p ../yourfilearchive/"$dir"
        mv "$file" ../yourhadoopdir/"$file"
    done
```

This script will simply recreate your files rather than move them into the your directories.

These are ofcourse will simply work for your txt files which are older than 2 days if you want to use hdfs s own commands I found great answer for that.

[Get files which are created in last 5 minutes in hadoop using shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39032539/get-files-which-are-created-in-last-5-minutes-in-hadoop-using-shell-script/39035616#39035616)

Comment: Looking for HDFS solution