# how to merge multiple csv file with one having same header

Tags: csv, unix, hdfs

In my hdfs folder I am getting my inputs files continuously. I wanted to merge multiple csv file having same header from last 15 min and make one csv file having one header. I tried with `-getmerge` but it did not work. any pointers please?

Answer (score 2):

I am referring below link to get the list of files which were processed in last '5 minutes'.

[Get the list of files processed in last 5 minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39032539/get-files-which-are-created-in-last-5-minutes-in-hadoop-using-shell-script)
Since you want to skip individual header and merge all the listed files with single header.
Can get those files to local unix as shown below:

```
#!/bin/bash

filenames=`hdfs dfs -ls /user/vikct001/dev/hadoop/external/csvfiles/part* | tr -s " " | cut -d' ' -f6-8 | grep "^[0-9]" | awk 'BEGIN{ MIN=5;LAST=60*MIN; "date +%s" | getline NOW } { cmd="date -d'\''"$1" "$2"'\'' +%s"; cmd | getline WHEN; DIFF=NOW-WHEN; if(DIFF < LAST){ print $3 }}' `

for file in $filenames
do
   #echo $file
   hdfs dfs -get ${file} /home/vikct001/user/vikrant/shellscript/testfiles
done
```

once you have the listed files at your local. can use below command to merge all the files with single header.

```
awk '(NR == 1) || (FNR > 1)' /home/vikct001/user/vikrant/shellscript/testfiles/part*.csv > bigfile.csv
```

Here's a link for more details on this.
[Merge csv with a single header](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/80611/merging-multiple-csv-files-without-merging-the-header/348619#348619)

There are couple of more commands as mentioned in above link but I found this is the most suitable.

Comment: above solution little bit complex. do we have any other suggestion get last 15 min all files or files older then one hours ?